# Python list with variable in reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have numbered my lists layer1, layer2 ...
I want to use a variable (playery) as the number in the lists name when calling it, so if playery was equal to 4, the list addressed would be layer4

```
layer1 = [".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
layer2 = [".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
layer3 = [".", ".", "■", ".", "."]
layer4 = [".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
layer5 = [".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
playerx = (3)
playery = (4)
(layer(playery - 1))[playerx-1]= (".")

(layer(playery))[playerx-1]= ("■")
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work

Comment: Use a list of layers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do.

```
layers = [[".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
          [".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
          [".", ".", "■", ".", "."],
          [".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
          [".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]

>> playerx = 3
>> playery = 4
>> layers[playery - 1][playerx - 1]= "."
>> layers[playery][playerx - 1]= "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2D array like this:

```
layers= [layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer5]
```

and if you want to get "■" you should type:

```
layers[2][2]
```